# How to not use bindActionCreators in mapdispatchtoprops?

Tags: reactjs, data-binding, redux

I don't want to use bindActionCreators in mapdispatchtoprops. What is the other way to dispatch action?

I am accessing it in componentdidmount() like below:

````````````
````````
 this.props.getEntityData.getEntitiesAction().then({})

 dispatching it as below:
  `````
  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      getEntityData : bindActionCreators(getEntitiesAction, dispatch)
   };
```````````
````````````

This is working and I am getting the data.
   But I don't want to use nindActionCreators. What is the other way to 
   dispatch action and how can I access it in in componentdidmount?

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators):

> The only use case for bindActionCreators is when you want to pass some action creators down to a component that isn't aware of Redux, and you don't want to pass dispatch or the Redux store to it.

You can import the action and pass it to the component through `connect`, like this:

```
import {action} from './actions';

...

componentDidMount() {
  this.props.action();
}

...

connect(mapStateToProps, {action})(Component)
```

If you don't need the store you can just pass in `null` instead of mapStateToProps.